# Assert that value from Context is not null in child component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-context

I'm building a Next.js/React app with TypeScript. I have a `UserContext` in `pages/_app.js` which provides a `user: User | null` object to all child components.

I also have a `ProtectedRoute` component to wrap pages which shouldn't be accessible without being logged in (it consumes the `user` from `UserContext` and redirects if `user === null`).

However, the type of `user` that children of `ProtectedRoute` see is still `User | null`. It should just be `User`, since we can't access a protected route without being logged in. **Is there a TypeScript or React design pattern that would accomplish this?**

I looked at non-null assertions with `!`, but those are default-disabled by ESLint and I don't want to do that in every child of `ProtectedRoute`. I also looked at [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), but not sure if there's a way to avoid doing that in every child component.

Ideally, the type of `user` from `UserContext` would change to just `User` instead of `User | null` if the component consuming the context is a child of `ProtectedRoute`.

Thank you!

EDIT: `ProtectedRoute` code:

```js
function ProtectedRoute({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  const { user } = useSupabase();  // This has type `User | null`
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      router.push("/login");  // There may be a more Next-specific way to do this...
    }
  }, [user, router]);
  return user ? children : null;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your `ProtectedRoute` component? You can probably just give a hint to TypeScript to allow for control-flow analysis.

Comment: Added, thanks @iz_

Comment: Ah, I thought you were passing `user` as a prop/render prop to `children`. As it stands, there probably isn't a clean a way to do this. If you don't want to use `!`, you can also get away with using optional chaining everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, also would like to avoid optional chaining (currently checking `user === null` in every child component)

Answer (score 3):

If you're **positive** that the component will never be rendered in a logged-out state, then you can use an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) in a custom hook to transform the type.

> Note that you're making a guarantee by throwing an error if the condition can't be met, and that this will [crash your component](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) if you use it incorrectly.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEE0HsFdQEwJZwHYHIAuoDOALSB3UfHAQ03RwFMtLQSAnWyeoqx0CygT1AGNIAtrQBm9QQC4AUAmTpK9YSV60AqjRYBvAL6S4lXgBsGI6Ml7oEkZKGg0AytAAOJAEYkaoABQBKcaA026n5q8qAAPqDI0AYGoFoA3Lr6RuzCpuaW1raUAEowciw+fljo9DIA5gDaALqJkuhcjrQAclbN0UYuBpQACmJN9BbUoAA8ACoANKAA0tyglAAecshwWKAA1tyQwqBjAHygALz+kqCgldOgMhtbO2PVfpeLy6szcwD8oK3I7TGu3eMLtUDn4xkDEglJJI0mYLFY6Fh1JhPItHPQ-KZ1sgCMgpgIsOV3sVShVfAikWtUZpTlcdp4AIRU7wcHBiQjISiEACi9DE9E8+PKoHen1QADUSAZoLQEGtFAYsFxUN4IVCYRl4dkHM43DQAILQTiyBC8MiUOBeMnfX6dbp9SADIZYEY5SjoaD0ZBjRqUEYNJrbQKUbWudyUPZTVDZeioA4aGn8ZAlUCMLDRTDHLVOUM0HyJM7uJGeVPpgB00cjAElkAA3SVIbDoM3K-Mpt0e6wlgyYdxfNodf69fryJ1+n2BrvoSPR2Oq6HpOHWe1yczmvKG2ieAK8HAIAxwRjWLR+be7-eHvwAKTsAA1S1zukJZHFmfGzonkwFo3EjkGQ7rKANI0LFNOQ4DzUAQCuNZsUIAArWxMBCegaSgj9MDEDcWEzGh1wKPNULAbIuWEYR9HQTwfCOONCLOWkvHpaNmUwgpS0cWwcE8AAiYADEgcoZC4lVaK0KZKgrFN8nkaphLOKDGHdT0gxYT4dz3A9KGsPwohiVsFI7Pgzw05BVSAA)

```ts
// You didn't show what these are or where they come from:
interface User {}
declare function useSupabase (): { user: User | null };
declare function useRouter (): string[];

type NonNullableProperties <T, Key extends keyof T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends Key ? NonNullable<T[K]> : T[K];
};

function assert (expr: unknown, msg?: string): asserts expr {
  if (!expr) throw new Error(msg ?? 'Value is falsy');
}

function useSupabaseAuthenticated (): NonNullableProperties<ReturnType<typeof useSupabase>, 'user'> {
  const result = useSupabase();
  assert(result.user, 'Invalid state');
  return result as NonNullableProperties<typeof result, 'user'>;
}

function ProtectedRoute ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  const { user } = useSupabaseAuthenticated(); // is now just User
  // const router = useRouter();
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (!user) router.push("/login");
  // }, [user, router]);
  // return user ? children : null;
  return children;
}
```